# How to add Swatches options to Recently viewed UI component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, swatches, recently-viewed

How to add swatches options for product item to a Recently viewed UI component?

I use the following code to show recently viewed block on the page

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed" name="recently_viewed" template="Magento_Catalog::product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml" after="-">
   <arguments>
       <argument name="uiComponent" xsi:type="string">widget_recently_viewed</argument>
       <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">4</argument>
       <argument name="show_attributes" xsi:type="string">name,image,price</argument>
       <argument name="show_buttons" xsi:type="string">add_to_cart,add_to_compare,add_to_wishlist</argument>
   </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: Hello Anton, Have you got an answer to this?